# PHP: how do I convert foreign characters from simple_html_dom to UTF8?

Tags: php, utf-8, simple-html-dom

I'm having some trouble with a string that comes from a webpage having foreign characters in it.

The string is generated by parsing the webpage using `str_get_html()`, followed by `$htmldom->innertext;` (simple_html_dom class library).

When I output the string using `htmlentities()` it is displayed fine; but using `explode()` on the string and printing the parts, I get a tilted block with a question mark in it for each foreign character.

I need to store the string in a `utf8` MySQL database, so I need the right foreign characters.

My page has a header with `utf8` character set.

I have already tried `mb_split()` and `preg_split()`, but those have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with :
https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

It has a great function that just converts anything to utf-8, no matter what source it's from (as long as it comes in Latin1 (iso 8859-1), Windows-1252 or UTF8 already, or a mix of them).

Many thanks go to Sebastian Grignoli.

Comment: If this solved your issue you should accept this answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP and UTF-8 isn't a very good combination. Some functions work fine with UTF-8, others don't, and the worst are those that are documented to work, but in fact do not (such as DOMDocument ).

You can use `mb_convert_encoding()` to convert multibyte characters to HTML entities, which usually provides an acceptable workaround:

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: ``utf8_encode()`` converts a iso-8859-1 string to utf-8, so that makes little sense if your source is already utf-8 ... Maybe the source document isn't in UTF-8?

Comment: I have no idea... it comes from an existing webpage, that I process with simple_html_dom,  how can I detect the encoding that webpage is in ?  (the same routine works fine with foreign characters with a different source webpage!)

Comment: Can you post the script you're using & the webpage you're fetching?

Comment: Alright ... But explode() and many other PHP functions still won't work with multibyte characters ... IMHO you would be better off figuring our the proper charset (For example from the Content-Type HTTP header) and using mb_convert_encoding() ... Read this as an introduction to character encodings: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html